# How to activate WebGL in Chromium Beta?

Tags: 10.04, chromium, webgl

Does anyone succeeded in activating WebGL in Chromium Beta in Ubuntu 10.04? I've tried everything at http://khronos.org/webgl/wiki/Getting_a_WebGL_Implementation but I still can't use http://bodybrowser.googlelabs.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First go to: [How do I browse a website that uses WebGL?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17803/how-do-i-browse-a-site-that-uses-webgl) where i answer a similar question. After that do the following:

Run chromium using the following parameter: `chromium --enable-webgl`

Chrome might or might no work with the parameter mention above, at least in the last 3 versions it failed for me on some PCs.

Comment: CYREX, thank you for your answer. I read the question you mention before, and I thought it was different to my question. I've tried everything that it is said on the links but WebGL is still not working. I think I'll have to wait a little bit more to use WebGL in my laptop.

Comment: No problem mate just glad to help. Let us both wait until webgl is correctly supported. Happy new year.